What are the benefits of using two containers of shared_ptr over one of unique_ptr and the other of raw pointers?
I'm working on a game, represented by the Game class, which owns every GameEntity and stores them in a container.
However, for convenience my Game class would also like to have a dedicated container for a specific type of GameEntity, for example PlayerGameEntity.
I've thought of 2 solutions using smart pointers, but I'm not experienced enough in C++ to know what would be the advantage of one solution over the other.
Solution A:
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameEntity>> gameEntities;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<PlayerGameEntity>> players;

void createPlayer()
{
    std::shared_ptr<PlayerGameEntity> player = std::make_shared<PlayerGameEntity>();
    gameEntities.emplace_back(player);
    players.emplace_back(player);
}

Solution B:
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameEntity>> gameEntities;
std::vector<PlayerGameEntity*> players;

void createPlayer()
{
    gameEntities.emplace_back(std::make_unique<PlayerGameEntity>());
    players.emplace_back(dynamic_cast<PlayerGameEntity*>(gameEntities.back().get())); // And is there a better way to get a pointer to the entity I've just created?
}

Again, my Game is the sole owner of these entities, and would communicate them to other systems in the form of raw pointers.
My understanding of solution B would be that removing a GameEntity from gameEntities would mark it for deletion, which I think makes the most sense for my case.

The less you deal with raw pointers, the less chances are that you will make a mistake using them (e.g. due to wrong handling of ownership etc.). So in general it is prefered to use smart pointers over raw ones.

While smart pointers are nice, I rather recommend you look at them from an ownership perspective. Who owns the objects? Perhaps you should use std::unique_ptr instead, and pass around references to the owned objects? Perhaps you should use plain non-owning pointers if there isn't any ownership semantics involved? What to use really depends on your requirements, analysis, design and use-cases.

I prefer using std::unique_ptr owning smart pointers, and non-owning raw pointers.  If the raw pointer is held onto after it was passed into a function call, that's a brittle point of failure if there is a possibility of a future dangling raw pointer — I try to eliminate or minimize those; or otherwise carefully document them.

It would probably be the least painful to put all your pointers in one container, and provide a separate interface to GameEntity objects and PlayerGameEntity objects.  Duplicating data tends to make a program slower and more fragile.

"for convenience". Now, several of your methods (CreatePlayer/RemovePlayer/...) have to deal with 2 vectors instead of one, you have to keep them in sync, ... Not so convenient IMO.

Instead of unique + raw pointers, you can also consider using the combination of shared + weak pointers (with some overhead). I would prefer the first option (for the sake of performance), but only if I was 100% sure that those raw pointers cannot be invalidated before being dereferenced at any circumstances.

In similar circumstances I have used a shared_ptr + std::weak_ptr

@DanielLangr: See my answer.

In both cases, you have to keep your containers in sync, though if you don’t, A will most likely not result in a crash but B is likely going to lead to one (if you forget to remove an element from players). Even worse, like always when accessing recently deleted objects, it might not crash during access and corrupt your program memory instead.
A potential downside of using shared_ptr is that your data structures suggest it will somehow appear in the final API and external objects might retain ownership of the game objects. It might be intended but since you are comparing with unique_ptr it is most likely not an intended behavior.
Also, in this kind of context, shared_ptr performance overhead is most likely irrelevant (until it isn’t when it finally appears in some profiling data).
Also, an implicit overhead of your data structure choice is that removals are going to be O(n) and if you remove multiple elements without a dedicated multiple removal function, O(mn)
Finally, if this is just a pet project or a student project, I’d personally go with the shared_ptr version which is basically working with a garbage collector.

If I put all of my unique pointers in a single container as suggested by Drew Dormann, and I want to call a function on all PlayerGameEntity, I would have to iterate over the whole container and dynamic_cast every Entity wouldn't I? Isn't it too costly in a game where they could be hundreds of entities, or is there another better way?

It is going to be costly yes, but the cost is always going to be relative to what you do with those players. If you are only getting the position, yes, the cast and virtual call overhead might start to show. If performance is critical, there are lots of other things to consider. You could also look at other designs like Data Oriented Programming and Entity Component systems. Also, objects and data structures don’t have intrinsic bad performance, you have to consider it in the context of how you use them. Start simple with this part of your code and refine it later on with profiling data.

I don't understand the need for syncing both containers in case of shared pointers. If there are 2 shared pointers — one in gameEntities and the other one in players — that share the same object, removing one of them will not cause this object to be deleted. The other pointer can still work on that.

The "need" is "assumed consistency" for code intended usage correctness. The assumption is that a PlayerGameEntity should be in both and removing it from one and not the other does not match what this code is trying to achieve.

Since it is the Game which owns the player entities, and (AFAICT) they do not get created or destroyed independently of being registered in the Game entities vector(s) - there is really no reason to use shared_ptr's Those are relevant where you have independent pieces of code which need the object kept alive, and you don't know which of them will stop needing it when, relative to the others.
So, what can you do instead, then?
Option 1: Single, simpler, data structure with a performance hit
You could always just use the main entities vector for the player entities, foregoing the second vector:
auto isPlayer = [](GameEntity const& ge) { /* determine if it's a player */ };
for ( auto& pe : gameEntities | std::views::filter(isPlayer) ) {
    /* do something with the player entity pe */
}

then you only store the single GameEntity vector.
Option 2: Separate the different kinds of entities
I'm betting you don't have that many kinds of game entities; and It's alsdo likely you don't encounter entities of a type that's unknown to you when compiling your Game class.
Well, in that case, you could just separate the entities of each type into its own vector - and then, you don't need pointers at all in the vector:
std::vector<Player> players;
std::vector<NonPlayerCharacter> npcs;
std::vector<Monster> monsters;
std::vector<WorldObject> world_objects;

This approach has some very nice properties:

Reduced complexity for many opertations which involve iterating entities.
Automatic and simple lifetime management.
No double-indirection when reading entity data (i.e. dereference a pointer to the entities vector data, then dereference a pointer to the actual object)
Makes it more straightforward to pass referencesd rather than pointersd.

but - there's a detriment, which is that vectors get their data reallocated, while if the entities themselves have individual locations in memory, a vector resize will not invalidate that; so a pointer the entity will remain valid.
You could create an enum, and a templated typedef which "maps" the enum to the vector. Then you might write something like gameEntities<entities::Player>, which would have type std::vector<Player>, while gameEntities<entities::Monster> would have type Monster.
You could also use view transformations to get ranges of GameEntity& to these different vectors - and those can be concatenated using std::ranges::views::concat - in case you want to iterate the entities of multiple types at once.
Option 3: "I'm lazy, I don't care about perf, and I want my player entities cache"
(Suggested also by @DanielLangr)
Switch your
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<PlayerGameEntity>> players;

into
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<PlayerGameEntity>> players;

this way, you can safely deleter players from the main entities vector, without worrying about them still being in the players cache - since lock()ing players which have been destructed will fail.
The benefit here is that you don't have to change almost any of your existing code. But IMHO this is kind of silly.
More ideas & other options
We're just getting started... you could:

Use indices into a storager area instead of pointers. After all, a pointer is 8 bytes! You don't have > 2^32 players, right? Probably not more than 2^3 I would say. So why store 8 bytes for each entity?
Don't de-allocate, use tombstones: Entities will have a boolean field which, when set, indicates the object is no longer in use and should be ignored. So, even if you point to it, you won't misuse it. And no need to track who holds a pointer to (or inderx of) that object - the user is assumed to respect the tombstone designation.
Use std::variant's instead of subclasses. There was this CppNow talk about designing a slimmer vector-of-variants.

and there are more potential ideas to consider.
